# Using System.Runtime.Caching

Tags: c#, caching, dll

I am using System.Runtime.Caching library.

I have problem when initiating this code

```
private ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
```

I get error

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Caching, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Before that, I use those classes and works OK. So it is not the problem accessing the assembly, as I initially thought.

```
    private CacheItemPolicy cacheItemPolicy; 
    cacheItemPolicy = new CacheItemPolicy();
    cacheItemPolicy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddHours(240);
```

Comment: .NET Framework or .NET Core? Old style or new Sdk-style project?

Comment: Can you see the class in the object browser in Visual Studio?

Comment: I'm using the latest Visual Studio and .net Standard. It is new SDK style project. All looks good. The compiler build projects OK. When I'm trying to access the code I recieve above error.